# Dynamically Generating HTML

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm an absolute beginner, been self-studying for two weeks in preparation for a bootcamp coming up in a month. In an effort to improve my skills and "learn to think like a developer", I've taken on a project which attempts to solve a real-world problem.

My wife runs a business requiring her to generate invoices for her clients. I am attempting to use HTML and JavaScript to build a web-based application which enables her to quickly create custom invoices instead of writing them out manually each time.

In the current version, a prompt requests a number from her. This number generates an equal number of three-column rows in HTML. This enables her to customize the invoice with the exact number of fields she needs.

Column 1 contains the product name. In the same row, column 2 contains the unit count, while column 3 contains the total cost of that product, which is the base price multiplied by the unit count. I want this calculation to occur upon a button click. But, I'm stuck.

In order to perform the math, I need to be able to get the integers from each row and column and pass them into a function. But because each row and column was generated automatically, they have no unique attributes and cannot thereby be identified. I am able to perform the math down each column, but not across each row.

As I'm so new, having only learned from a couple introductory Codecademy courses and some YouTube videos, I don't know how to evaluate whether I'm approaching the project entirely wrong, or if there's some trick I'm missing, or if there's just something haven't learned yet. If someone with some expertise could nudge me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

I've attached all the code to this post. Apologies if it's a horrible mess. Go easy on me, I'm a beginner!

```html
const invDate = Date();
var field = "<label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input type=text name='item'>" +             
"<label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input type='number' name='qty'>" + 
"<label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input type='number' name='price'> <br><br>";

document.getElementById('newInvoice').onclick = function(){

  let invoicedName = prompt('Who is this invoice made out to?', 'Enter a name');
  let productFields = Number(prompt('How many product names on this invoice?', 'Please enter a number'));  
  let fields = ''
  let dynHtml = ''
      if (invoicedName != null && productFields != null) {                                          
      for (let i = 1; i <= productFields; i++) { 
      fields += field };
    } else { alert('Please enter valid inputs.'); 
  };
  dynHtml = "<center><img src ='logo.jpg'><br></br>" +                                              
            "<h1>INVOICE</h1>" +
            "<p>Prepared for: <b>" + invoicedName + "</b>, on" +
            "<p>" + invDate + "</p><br></br>" +
            fields + "<br></br>" +
            "<button id ='calculate'>Calculate</button></center>";
  document.write(dynHtml);
                                                                                                    
  document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function getQtyFields() {
      
    let qtyInputs = document.getElementsByName('qty'),
          resultQty = 0;
      for ( let j = 0; j < qtyInputs.length; j++ ) {
          if ( qtyInputs[j].id.indexOf('qty') == 0 ) {
              let num = parseFloat( qtyInputs[j].value );
              if( !isNaN(num) ) resultQty += num;
          }
      }
    let priceInputs = document.getElementsByName('price'),
          resultPrice = 0;
      for( let k = 0; k < priceInputs.length; k++ ) {
          if( priceInputs[k].id.indexOf('price') == 0 ) {
              let num = parseFloat( priceInputs[k].value );
              if( !isNaN(num) ) resultPrice += num;
          }
      }
      alert(resultQty); alert(resultPrice)
  }
}
```

Here's Screenshot,
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It would make sense to generate your `<input>` elements with something unique to the row they're part of. Then you can select them accordingly. You might consider using data attributes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), but there are plenty of ways to do it. Learning a popular framework might make even more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your main issue is finding a way to give every input field within their own row their own unique identifier. This way you can calaulate the price for each row and insert it into the price field.

You first have to start with the fields:

```js
var field = "<label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input type=text name='item'>" +             
"<label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input type='number' name='qty'>" + 
"<label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input type='number' name='price'> <br><br>";

document.getElementById('newInvoice').onclick = function(){

   ...

      for (let i = 1; i <= productFields; i++) { 
      fields += field };

   ...
  };
```

Every group needs its own identifier. That way you can later refer to every input in each row to calculate the sub total price. The `class` attribute is something you can assign to multiple elements to refer to them later. This `class` can be anything as long as it doesn't conflict with the `class` for any other row. You can use the `i` of the loop as your identifier, since it changes with every loop.

```js
     for (let i = 1; i <= productFields; i++) { 

       var field = "<label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type=text name='item'>" +             
       "<label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type='number' name='qty'>" + 
       "<label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type='number' name='price'> <br><br>";

      fields += field 
};
```

This will add the class `row-{i}` to every field in every row. Better yet, you can refactor this into its own function

```js
function generateFields(i) {
       return "<label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type=text name='item'>" +             
       "<label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type='number' name='qty'>" + 
       "<label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input class='row-" + i + "' type='number' name='price'> <br><br>";
}

     for (let i = 1; i <= productFields; i++) { 
        
      fields += generateFields(i);
};
```

You get something similar to the following html

```html
    <label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input type=text class='row-1' name='item'>              
    <label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input type='number' class='row-1' name='qty'> 
    <label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input type='number' class='row-1' name='price'> <br><br>

    <label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input type=text class='row-2' name='item'>              
    <label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input type='number' class='row-2' name='qty'> 
    <label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input type='number' class='row-2' name='price'> <br><br>

    <label for='Item'>Item:</label> <input type=text class='row-3' name='item'>              
    <label for='qty'> Qty: </label> <input type='number' class='row-3' name='qty'> 
    <label for='Price'> Price ($):</label> <input type='number' class='row-3' name='price'> <br><br>
```

Now in your calculate function, you can refer to these rows and calculate their price. Here you can loop over the 'item' input fields.

```js
  document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function getQtyFields() {
         let itemInputs= document.getElementsByName('item')

         for(let i = 0; i < itemInputs.length; i++){
           const identifier = itemInputs[i].className // get the class name of every item ex. 'row-1'

           const row = document.getElementsByClassName(identifier);
         }

     ...
 }
```

`row` is now an `HTMLCollection` which contains the `item`, `qty`, and `price` for each row. With `HTMLCollections` you can select any of its elements by its name using `.namedItem(<name>)`

```js
         for(let i = 0; i < itemInputs.length; i++){
           const identifier = itemInputs[i].className // get the class name of every item ex. 'row-1'

           const row = document.getElementsByClassName(identifier);  // ex. 'row-1'
           
           const qty = row.namedItem('qty').value;
           const basePrice = [YOUR BASE PRICE];

           const itemSubTotal = basePrice * qty; // heres is your item sub total!
         }
```

You can now insert the price `price` into the  input field for that row.

```js
         for(let i = 0; i < itemInputs.length; i++){
           const identifier = itemInputs[i].className // get the class name of every item ex. 'row-1'

           const row = document.getElementsByClassName(identifier); // ex. 'row-1'
           
           const qty = row.namedItem('qty').value;
           const basePrice = [YOUR BASE PRICE];

           const itemSubTotal = basePrice * qty; // heres is your item sub total!

           const price = row.namedItem('price');
           price.value = itemSubTotal; // insert subtotal inside the price field
         }
```

Now once you click on calculate, you should see the alerts for total price and total quantity and should see the `price` input fields filled with the calculated price.

This solution is very basic and shouldn't introduce any new concepts you don't know. Later on in your bootcamp, you will learn will about design patterns and frameworks that can make these kind of projects easier to manage and scale.

Hit me up if run into any problems or have any other questions!

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply. With your help, each field now has unique attributes. However, I'm still having trouble accessing those attributes and putting them to use.

After much tinkering, I keep running into 'getElementsByClassName is undefined.' I attempted several workarounds, such as iterating the different fields by name identifiers instead of class name identifiers. This has yielded no progress. I'll keep poking at it, but if you might be able to help me understand why getElementsByClassName, which is clearly defined, keeps turning up as "undefined, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry about that. `getElementsByClassName` is a typo and should be `document.getElementsByClassName` as the method is only available on the `document` object. I have already edited my answer.

Comment: No worries. That's something I should have been able to pick up on. I suppose sometimes the problem is much simpler than we expect! Thank you again. I think I can take it from here; there's a few more features I need to add but you got me unstuck. Appreciate it!